# what is Iris in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on and assignment called kmeans clustering on Iris data.

private Iris[] data;

I would like to know what is Iris[] in the above statement. Is it just a array or multidimensional array? what data type is storing in it?

Comment: It's an array of Iris insrances. I don't recognize that class, but presumably it's either a class you wrote, or a class provided by a library you're using.

Comment: It is an array of `Iris` objects. You should re-read the chapter on Java arrays, because multidimensional arrays have as many `[]` as dimensions, e.g. a 3D array would be `Iris[][][]`, and because the name before the `[]` *is* the data type. In short, your Java manual would have already given you both answers, if you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an multi-dimensional array. You should be able to find the package of Iris by looking at the `import` statements at the top of the class file. So navigate to that package and read the Javadocs of Iris class. It should be able to give you an idea what it does.

Comment: The Iris Flower dataset is a dataset from statistics and is heavily borrowed by researchers in machine learning. It contains 150 instances (rows) and 4 attributes (columns) and a class attribute for the species of iris flower (one of setosa, versicolor, and virginica). You can read more about Iris flower dataset on Wikipedia.